# Changing Action Bar items and title on adding Fragments

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-actionbar

Let's say I have a `FragmentA` visible.

I add a `FragmentB` (keyword: `add`, not `replace`), add it to the `Fragment` back stack and commit.

The issues I'm having doing this is:

1) The action buttons of the action menu of `FragmentB` are added, but those of `FragmentA` are not removed.

2) The title of the `ActionBar` does not change (despite calling `getActivity().setTitle("FragmentB")` in `onResume()` of `FragmentB`.

I can resolve both of these by calling `replace` instead of `add` when showing `FragmentB` however, for quite a few reasons I specifically need to `add` the Fragment instead (one of them being, I need to retain the state of `FragmentA` while showing B).

So how would I go about updating the `ActionBar` correctly as described?

Answer (score 1):

Try this piece of code:

```
getActivity().getActionBar().setTitle("FragmentB");
```

Answer (score 0):

Use this code in your Activity.. (for setting title to your fragment).

```
public void setActionBarTitle(String title) {
    getSupportActionBar().setDisplayOptions(ActionBar.DISPLAY_SHOW_TITLE);
    getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
    getSupportActionBar().setTitle(title);
}
```

from your fragment onResume(), call this using

```
// Set title bar
((MyActivity) getActivity())
            .setActionBarTitle("Fragment A");
```

and in each fragment you need to override onCreateOptionsMenu() to load your menus of that fragment.